# GRUB menu does not show up after installing linux mint 18 alongside Windows 10 during boot

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I have installed linux mint 18 alongside Windows 10 with UEFI in HP 240 G1 Notebook. After installation, the grub did not show up. and it booted me directly into windows 10. But when I press esc button at startup and then press F9 it shows os boot loader and ubuntu. When I press F10 it open bios setup and in system configuration => boot options => os boot manager there doesnot show linux and windows.

Can anyone help me bringing up the Grub boot menu at startup?

In Windows, I also entered the command bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi in cmd, but still the boot menu does not show up.

Comment: You should go to the EFI setup of your machine your problem is probably there, in boot options for efi, you will have to select the grub.efi or debian.efi file in the list, instead of windows, but this configuration depends so much in your machine... Sometimes you have a security flag open that only accepts the Windows binaries on the efi boot. Remember EFI does not boot disks but files inside the EFI partition. Normally grub create a new file there, and bios was able to recognize it without any configurations, but sometime the windows file are priorized, and you need to configure it manually.